# Stanford's Lexical parser not being detected in java code

Tags: java, parsing, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to parse a sentence using the Stanford's lexical parser. I copied the code from [How can I integrate stanford parser software in my java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429106/how-can-i-integrate-stanford-parser-software-in-my-java-program). But when I run this code, it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class lexparser
  location: class edu.stanford.nlp.parser
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.<clinit>(parser.java:10)
/home/shivam/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

I have integrated the Stanford's corenlp jar files with the project. I am attaching the screenshot of the jar files included in my library.
[image]
When I open the stanford-corenlp.jar file, I can see parser inside edu/stanford/nlp and also can see lexparser inside parser.

Comment: Get a smarter IDE: IntelliJ.  It's probably Eclipse or Netbeans shenanigans: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386076/uncompilable-source-code-runtimeexception-in-netbeans

Comment: You've copied the JAR, but is it on your build path?

Comment: Why do you have a lowercase `parser.java` file? And why are you using the `edu.stanford.nlp` namespace in your own project? That said, none of these should cause the problem you're describing. Maybe a simple `make clean && make` -- i.e., rebuild the project? Otherwise, as @LeeCambl suggested, it might be a classpath issue.